# android API key on a mac

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, keytool, api-key

I am trying to get a google API key to add google maps to my application.  I have found a tutorial and created a keystore for my application in eclipse. I am having trouble figuring out how to get the fingerprint.  I cannot seem to find the keytool in any of the directories to enter the command to get the fingerprint.  I went to Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine, but the directory after that is empty.  Is there another file or a place where the keytool can be found in the directory?  I have looked at several tutorials including the android one and have not had much luck.  Any ideas>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

keytool seems to be in your PATH variable -> so just type keytool inside your terminal and it should start.

```
$ whereis keytool
/usr/bin/keytool
```